# Extremum of the cyclic sum of polynomial ratios (same degree)

Tags: inequality, reference-request, polynomials, optimization

I've noticed a few times (probably nothing new) that cyclic sums (assuming $x, y, z > 0$) like:

$\frac{x^2+y^2}{yz} + \frac{y^2+z^2}{zx} + \frac{z^2+x^2}{xy}$,

where in each of the 3 ratios, all terms in both the numerator and denominator polynomials have the same degree, reach an extremum when $x=y=z$.

It's interesting and I want to work on proving as generalized a version of this result as possible ($n$ variables, allowing negative signs in polynomials, etc.). The current generalized version I have in mind is as follows:

Let $x_i > 0$, with $i \in \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$. Suppose $f_1(x_i)$ and $f_2(x_i)$ are polynomials of the same degree $m$ and with a finite number of terms, such that each term in each polynomial is of the form $c_k\prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{y_i}$, where $y_i \in \mathbb{N}$ for all $i \in \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n y_i = m$. Then

$\sum_{p}\frac{f_1(x_i)}{f_2(x_i)}$ attains an extremum when $x_1 = x_2 = \ldots = x_n$, where the summation is over all the cyclic permutations of $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$.

Before that, I'd appreciate clarification on what exactly would be the prerequisites and what all I would need to learn in order to tackle a problem like this. Also, I'd be grateful if someone can tell me what work has been done or what results already exist on this sort of a problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Using the AM-GM inequality
\begin{align}
\frac{x^2 + y^2}{yz} + \frac{y^2 + z^2}{zx} + \frac{z^2 + x^2}{xy} &= \frac{x^3 + xy^2 + y^3 + yz^2 + z^3 + zx^2}{xyz}\\
&\geq \frac{6\sqrt[6]{x^6 y^6 z^6}}{xyz}= \frac{6xyz}{xyz} = 6
\end{align}
This means the sum has an minimum value of 6. Equality will occur in AM-GM when all terms of the arithmetic mean are the same. That means equality will occur if
\begin{equation}
x^3 = xy^2 = y^3 =yz^2 = z^3 = zx^2
\end{equation}
Since $x^3 = zx^2$ if follows that $x = z$, and since $y^3 = xy^2$ if follows that $y = x$. Therefore the minimum will occur when $x = y = z$. Note that this is not the only case for extremum, as this requires the condition that $x,y,z \geq 0$.

Comment: Thanks! But I'm not looking for a proof of the example I included in the question. The example was only to illustrate a result whose generalization I want to work on. The question is basically a reference request and to ask others what existing research, if any, exists regarding such a generalized conjecture.

Comment: @ShirishKulhari In order to answer that question you need to define the general form of this symmetric sum, as many symmetric sums may have take this form for a specific case.

Comment: I edited the question to include a tentative idea of what the generalized form of the problem would look like.